# How do i design a shape (like in picture) in WPF XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, shapes

i just want to make with WPF using the XAML such a shape :
[image: shape]

the shape is in red, kind of box with rectangle like quotation.
can you help ?
thanks alot.

Comment: Either use Microsoft Expression Design and copy paste the XAML, or export from another program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt at something similar to your diagram.  Is it of help to you?

```
    <Grid Width="602">
        <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="#FFFFCC" Data="M 0,50 400,50 450,0 500,50 600,50 600,150 0,150 0,50" />
        <Grid Margin="0,50,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="Blah blah blah - blah blah?" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10" />
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10">
                <Button Width="100" Content="Yes" />
                <Button Width="100" Content="No" Margin="50,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```